# Xcode-playground's timeline: white text on white background

Tags: swift, xcode6, swift-playground

I'm playing with playground in Xcode 6 and face an issue with the playground's timeline.
Specifically, both the text and background are in white colour which make it unable to see.
To see the text, I have to select each line in the panel so that it can become visible - see image:

[image]

Anyone got the same problem and have solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set white text color for Plain Text in Xcode preferences (Fonts & Colors)? Try to change to dark one. There are no separate font settings for timeline output text yet.